# How to turn off hint in Wild Web Developer

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, wildwebdeveloper, eclipse-2020-06

After updating my Eclipse IDE from 2020-03 to 2020-06 I also had to install Wild Web Developer due to the fact that with the 2020-06 release JSDT is no longer supported.

Looks good so far in spite of the annoying hint "This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration"

Is there any way to disable this hint?